# DST not matching between browsers for old dates

Tags: .net, google-chrome, firefox, timezone, momentjs

In Chrome, Firefox and Opera (on Windows 10 and/or Mac), running `moment('1957-10-19').isDST()` returns `false`

In Edge and IE11 (on Windows) and Yandex (on Windows and Mac) and Safari (on a Mac and iPhone), the same code returns `true`

In C# .NET, `new DateTime(1957, 10, 19).IsDaylightSavingTime()` returns `true`

Which ones are correct?

Is there a good way to handle this?

I discovered this when serializing dates like this from C# to JavaScript. Because the server and client don't agree on whether the date in DST, the date ended up an hour earlier, at 11 pm the previous day.

*This is not necessarily a moment.js issue, as the underlying JavaScript calculates to the same answer. These tests were done at the momentjs.com website from a computer in the "America/Denver" timezone and on computers in BrowserStack which are in the "America/Los_Angeles" timezone.*

Comment: This has been asked a few times, but it comes down to Windows not tracking historical time zone data back that far (thus applying more recent rules), and some browsers carrying their own time zone data. (`false` is correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zoneinfo has `America/Denver` not observing DST until 1965.

https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2019a/northamerica#L455-L467

```
> moment.tz('1965-06-01','America/Denver').isDST()
true
> moment.tz('1964-06-01','America/Denver').isDST()
false
```

(Using June 1st to avoid thinking about the transition date, which was not uniform across the US in the past.)

It has `America/Los_Angeles` observing DST with the rest of the US since 1918.

```
> moment.tz('1918-06-01','America/Los_Angeles').isDST()
true
> moment.tz('1917-06-01','America/Los_Angeles').isDST()
false
```

If you require consistent historic times, use `moment-timezone` instead of relying on the browser's `Date` object, which is what `moment` does if you don't specify a timezone. Cross-platform inconsistencies and various versions of browsers are working against you here, as is Javascript for not requiring correct behavior. (The .NET framework is just wrong, I suppose, but I don't know anything about why; look into [nodatime](/questions/tagged/nodatime).)

Use `moment.tz.guess()` if you need to translate the user's current time into *some* timezone (which is a guess, as you might guess).